# ¿Cómo hago una operación de suma todo en la misma línea?

Tags: java, operador

Tengo un ejemplo de una suma entre dos números, pero a mi me gustaría que en vez de pedir de uno en uno los números que escriba directamente 2+2 en el scanner y me haga la suma en vez de poner 2 enter 2 enter.

No se si me explico bien.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
float num1;
float num2;
    
System.out.println("Introduza primer numero");
num1 = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Introduzca segundo numero");
num2 = scanner.nextInt();
    
float resultado = num1 + num2;
System.out.println("Resultado: " + resultado);
```

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres resolver una operación de suma en una sola línea, mediante Scanner podrías pasarle la operación como tipo cadena y después usar expresiones regulares para poder realizar la suma identificando el símbolo "+", el siguiente código seria útil para lo que solicitas, saludos.

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese su operacion");
        String operacion = sc.next();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[+-]?[0-9]+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(operacion);
        Integer suma = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            suma += Integer.valueOf(matcher.group());
        }
        System.out.println(suma);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gran respuesta, solamente habría que tener cuidado con los inputs como "99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 - 1"

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la forma que más se adecua a tu caso es leer la cadena de texto entera y de esa cadena de texto, interpretar la suma.

**También recuerda que es muy importante cerrar tu Scanner.**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

//      Se lee la línea como texto
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();

//      La línea antes mencionada, ahora será lo que leerá tu scanner
        scanner = new Scanner(input);
        int total = 0;

//      Mientras aún puedas leer algo de tu cadena
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
//          Si es entero (base 10)
            if (scanner.hasNextInt())
//              Al total súmale lo que hayas leído
                total += scanner.nextInt();
//          De lo contrario
            else
//              Imprime que esa parte de tu cadena se va a omitir
                System.out.println("Saltando " + scanner.next());
        }

        scanner.close();
        System.out.println("La suma es: " + total);
    }
}
```

**Notas:**

- Las operaciones deben ir separadas por un espacio:

  > "5 +6 -8" ✅✅✅
  >
  > "5+6-8" ❌❌❌
- Si omites el signo positivo se toma como suma

  > "5 4" -> 9
- [`Scanner#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) sólo acepta números enteros, si quieres todos los reales, usa `hasNextDouble` y `nextDouble`

**Input 1**

```
5 -9 +3 +6 -2 +8 +11
```

**Output 1**

```
La suma es: 22
```

**Input 2**

```
5 -1 -a b +1
```

**Output 2**

```
Saltando -a
Saltando b
La suma es: 5
```

Answer (score -2):

Si te entiendo bien quieres realizar lo mismo con menos lineas de codigo.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
System.out.println("Se sumara: "+ scanner.nextInt() +"+"+ scanner.nextInt());
System.out.println("Resultado: " + (scanner.nextInt()+scanner.nextInt()));
```

Comment: No, lo que quiero es que solamente haya un scanner, en plan scanner.next(); y yo escriba por ejemplo "2 + 2" y me lo haga que sepa que yo escribo un 2 y escribo un signo de operar y luego el 2 numero. Como las calculadoras que todo va en la misma linea